# Symfony 4 command and Swift Mailer issue

Tags: symfony4, swiftmailer

I'm trying to automate a call to a controller which sends email.
So I would like to be able to call this controller from a symfony command.
The controller function works when I call the url from my browser. But when i call the function from my command i get errors from Swift Mailer, it asks me to provide an argument in order to construct the swift mailer ($mailer).

I have tried to inject \Swift_Mailer inside the call of my action but it justs shows me another argument error for the Swift_Transport.

Here is the code for my Command file and the signature and beginning of my Controller action:

```
//../src/Command/mailCommand.php
class mailCommand extends Command {

//...

public function execute (InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        $controller = new MailController();
        //try 1
        $controller->warningMailAction();
        //try 2
        //$transport = (new \Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp://smtp.myadress.fr', 25));
        // $controller->warningMailAction(new \Swift_Mailer($transport));
        $output->writeln('coucou !');
    }
}

//---------------------------------------
//../src/Controller/MailController.php

public function warningMailAction(\Swift_Mailer $mailer) {}
```

I run on symfony 4.3.2, I don't know how to fix this, everything i try leads me to more error. Every help is appreciated, tell me if you need more of my code to understand the problem

Comment: I forgot to post the error message:
`Too few arguments to function App\Controller\MailController::warningMailAction(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/ParcAuto/src/Command/mailCommand.php on line 41 and exa
  ctly 1 expected`

Comment: To eliminate your error, have you tried `$controller->warningMailAction(new \Swift_Mailer);`?

Comment: Yes i have, then i have a error message saying that i Swift_Mailer construct requires an argument
In order to solve this problem i tryed a second method (look at the //try 2) of my code above

Comment: Calling the action like this seems to solve the mailer issue:
`$transport = (new \Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp://smtp.myaddress.fr', 25,null));`
`$controller::warningMailAction(new \Swift_Mailer($transport));`
The error following this is `\FatalThrowableError: Using $this when not in object context`, the error comes  inside the controller where i call doctrine and access my database.

Comment: That's a totally separate question, so you should start a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

A `Controller` is a `ServiceSubscriber`. This means that upon instancing, the container injects some basic services into it.

By calling `new` you are instancing it directly without using the container and the services it uses aren't there. You could pass the `Container` via the `setContainer` method, or just inject the Controller into your command, its instancing will be taken care of by the container.

You just have to pass your controller dependency to your command `__construct`:

```
use App\Controller;

class mailCommand extends Command 
{
    private $controller;

    public function __construct(MailController $mailController)
    {
        $this->controller = $mailController;
    }

    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->controller->mailWarning(...);
        // Other stuff
    }
}
```

However, controllers are special since they can receive additional services injected in their methods, as is the case with `mailWarning`. This happens during the controller resolution phase. Since this will be called via a command, you will have to take care of this dependency too. Instead of instancing it manually you could get it from the container as well:

```
public function __construct(MailController $mailController, \SwiftMailer $mailer)
```

You can learn more about how all this works in the [Service Container Reference](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response, i'm new too symfony. So even though i understood that my controller could be seen by symfony as a service. I do not understand totally how **containers** work really.
If i understand you correctly, my options are:  
1) Call my MailController throught a Container.  
2) Passing my controller to the command
I'll try to see how i can do one of these things

Comment: I have been going throught the Service Container Reference since yesterday but unsuccessfully.
I will try your solution, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think it works. Thanks to your valuable help @msg.
I'll post here my final code in case it could be usefull for anyone having the same trouble.

**This is my mailCommand.php**

```
public function __construct(MailController $mailController, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    $this->controller = $mailController;
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
    parent::__construct();
}

protected function configure () {
    static $defaultName = 'app:mailAuto';
    $this->setName($defaultName);
    $this->setDescription("Permet d'envoyer des mails automatiquement lorsque le parc n'est pas à jour");
    $this->setHelp("Je serai affiche si on lance la commande bin/console app:mailAuto -h");
}

public function execute (InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
    $this->controller->warningMailAction($this->mailer);
    $output->writeln('Hello there !');
}
```

Inside my controller i have not changed anything.
I use the $mailer normally.

Thank you to everybody who helped me.